# Can someone recommend a program to aid a butcher?

Tags: 14.04

New to Linux and pretty much heavy computer usage.

I was wondering, I'm trying to come up with a program to aid in my job's performance, I work as a butcher and was wondering how to program a data table that I can enter in items I have packaged, priced, and their respective "sell by dates".

Thanks for the help!

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 BTW.

Comment: How much data are we talking about? And how efficient does it have to be? Libreoffice calc as shown in Cornelius answer can work if it is a small set. It is also possible with a database like mysql + mysql workbench (but that might be overkill ;-) )

Comment: There are also online methods: it is possible to create a database online for free and use that.

Comment: hmmm it has to hold up to five days of data at the very least all our fresh cut meat has a 5 day shelf life

Comment: and ill also look inot the online sources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **LibreOffice Calc**:

[image]

It is included by default in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Hmm haven’t looked into that yet thank you for answering me though it says to not thank in comments